# Not able to animate after frame 30

Tags: keyframes

I have set up a simple rig with IKs and am not able to keyframe the bones properly.
Although I select all bones before keyframing it, it seems that I'm not able to animate any bone after frame 30. Is this a bug? 
I currently use Blender 2.78 a.

This is my .blend file: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unpin the animation in the NLA editor as shown below and the animation will be there after frame 30 normally

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have converted your action to an [NLA strip](https://www.blender.org/manual/de/editors/nla/tracks_strips.html#tracks-strips). Outside the range of the NLA strip the action is no longer shown.

1. Go to the NLA editor. Select the strip. Press <kbd>X</kbd> to delete it.
   [image]
2. Go to the Dopesheet. Set it to **Action Editor** mode and choose the action you were working on (which we just deleted in the NLA editor). Now you can work on the full action again.

You probably pressed this button, then continued to edit your action.

Comment: how do i set it to action editor?

Comment: @Tejas - select it in the [mode menu in the dopesheet header](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/dope_sheet/introduction.html#dope-sheet-modes).